# zurb foundation into an existing django project

Tags: css, django, zurb-foundation

i would like to use Foundation 6 in my django project but it seems hard to do.
To work with sass, I have to use the cli and create a foundation project and it's not what I want because I already have a django project.
I tried to copy all files from scss folder into django but I always have errors when sublim text compile files to css.
Do someone has an experience with the same case ?